# Calendar API Response with '403: Daily Limit Exceeded' - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-calendar-api

I started with an little application for showing some relevant information to our developer team, which is collected from different sources. Like google calendar, our project backoffice, an openarena server-logs etc.

I started with an web application, but then decided to switch the project to an chrome extension. Now i already had the google calendar integration up and running using the V3 Javascript(alpha) Client-Lib. This wasn't working anymore because i had to change the OAUTH dance, from the one for web-apps, to the one for packaged/installed apps.

For this i followed the tutorial (It's my first extension.) http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html and got the OAUTH dance working again. Now i'am trying to request my calendar-data from the google api using the signedRequest-Methode from the tutorial, but alway receive the response "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" (Api Console shows i haven't performed any request).

Maybe someone has an idea what i am doing wrong here, because i tried everthing i could think about. Thanks in advance, Florian

Code - 
manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "MIS",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Monitor Information System",
    "background_page": "background.html",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/mis/icon.png",
        "default_title": "Mis"
    },

    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/",
    "https://www.google.com/"]
}
```

background.html:

```
...         
oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage
({
'request_url':'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
'authorize_url':'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
'access_url':'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',
'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
'app_name': 'Mis'
}); 
...
```

main.html Methode call:

```
function performCalendarEventsRequest(calendarId)
{
var requestUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+calendarId+'/events';
var request = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
      'GData-Version': '3.0',
      'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'
    },
    'parameters': {
      'alt': 'json'
    },
    'body': 'Data to send'
  };

 oauth.sendSignedRequest(requestUrl, calendarEventsRequestCallback, request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your consumer key and secret are both set as `anonymous` you are not identifying your application in any way.

You can either replace these with the Client ID and Client secret values respectively, which can be found on the API Access tab on your projects page in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/), or you can pass the API key (found just under the auth tokens on the same page) using an additional `key` parameter.

This is the same for most [Google APIs](http://code.google.com/more/).

**Source:** http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#APIKey

Comment: Thx for your comment, but you are incorrect. As i stated i am developing a chrome extension and therefore i have to use the oaut 'dance' for installed/packaged application (as described in the link i provided). Also the authentication process returns successful and am able to perform signed Request, which lead to the unexpected error.

Comment: I understand you're using OAuth as I did the very same for [my extension](https://github.com/neocotic/template) which uses the Google URL Shortener API and I had this exact problem because I wasn't letting the API know what my application was. Did you at least attempt my suggestion?

Comment: Didn't meant to insult you, sry. Thx for taking the time to respond. Tried it before leading to error 401: Invalid Credentials, which i expected to be caused by setting the the consumerId and consumerSecret. Wasn't quite sure if i had everything else right back then, so i tried it again leading to the same error... but then i recognized that the api explorer always appends the api key which i thought i wouldn't need in this case.

Comment: I tried it like in api explorer with set key value in url and consumerID/SECRET and with anonymous. With anonymous i got the response <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"><error><domain>GData</domain><code>unsupportedOutputFormat</code><location type="parameter">alt</location><internalReason>Unsupported Output Format</internalReason></error></errors>`. That seems to me that the call was successful but it tries to return jason to the XMLHttpRequest... Any ideas? thx in advance

Comment: Don't worry, I wasn't insulted. I have it set up so that `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` are both `anonymous` and my API key is passed as a parameter in the query string. Regarding JSON, what form did you expect/want the response to be in? As far as I can tell [JSON is the only option](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html#working_with_data).

Comment: Any useful response would be create for now... I did the same app as web-app before and just wanted to try the extension features, so json would be great because i already have the code for processing it afterwards. But it seems to me that the sendSignedRequest-methode uses the XMLHttpRequest-Methode. Could that be the source of the problem? Do i have any alternatives?

Comment: I just had a look at the XML response you received. This call is unsuccessful because you're passing an unrecognized parameter (`alt=json`). Although this parameter is used in the OAuth tutorial, it is not included in the Google Calendar API which [only recognizes specific parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#query-params). Using `application/json` for your content-type header should avoid XML responses. Also, I hope you aren't sending `Data to send` in your actual request as this could cause issues (removing this property completely is probably best).

Comment: thx to you i got it working right now... Additional to the steps you suggested i added the parameter 'key' passing my api. Without the api-key it still wasn't working, althoug in the documentation was stated that this parameter isn't required if you are passing a Oauth token. So i guess best is to always include it.

Comment: As I said previously, Google API's do require the API key to avoid this pitfall when being sent from a Chrome extension; otherwise they can't know what your application is and treat you like a single person (where call limits are quite low).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was stuck in the same error using the PHP implementation (Beta) of the API (2016-01-06), because I initially thought the `setAuthConfigFile` was all it was needed:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('MyCalendarAppName');
$client->setAuthConfigFile(APPPATH.'client_secret.json'); //file downloaded from GDC:
//  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=YOUR-PROJECT-ID
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

The error was not really due to a "daily limit" of requests but to the fact that I (owner of the Google account) hadn't explicitly given access permissions to the calendar. This is how to do it:

1. access the URL returned by the `createAuthUrl()` method (which can be invoked before calling the service);
2. a "Deny" and "Allow" form for accessing the calendars shows up – press **Allow**;
3. a code is returned – copy&paste this code to the `authenticate($code)` method and voilá, no more **403: Daily Limit Exceeded** errors.

For doing this, just use the following lines before invoking the service:

```
//$client->createAuthUrl();
// - invoke the method above one time only: returns a URL with the "Allow" form
//   which will give the code for authentication
$client->authenticate('YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client); //invokes the Calendar service
```

However, this will allow a **one time access** to the calendar. If you try this twice, you get:

> Google_Auth_Exception: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed.'

Meaning that a token is needed to reaccess the calendar with the **reedemed code**. This token is returned by the `authenticate` method and can be assigned to the client through the `setAccessToken` method:

```
//get the access token you previously stored or get a new one to be stored:
$accessToken = $client->authenticate('YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE');
//after the if-else blocks...
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
//refresh the token if it's expired
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
  $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

The goal is to reuse that access token repeatedly (implicitly also reusing the redeemed code) and only invoke a `refreshToken` when the token expires. [Google's quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) creates a specific file for storing this token (calendar-php-quickstart.json) and only uses the `authenticate` method when the token is not found in that file. I.e. the `setAccessToken` is the only Client authentication method (besides the `setAuthConfigFile`) that needs to be used in subsequent requests.

I only fully understood this [OAuth 2.0 logic](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) by going through these errors and since this question attracted so many people already, perhaps this may help others...